# What is the difference between Software Architecture Recovery and Software Remodularization in the context of Reverse Engineering?

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, binary-analysis, software-security

In the reverse engineering scenario, after extracting a representation of the code, it is often useful to recover/ reconstruct the architecture of the software (for eg. when reverse engineering java programs, recovering packages from classes). I am particularly concerned with the modules view of Software Architecture. To my understanding when we try to recover the modular architecture of a software, it is same as software remodularization. Is there a difference?

Comment: The former is understanding the existing modular structure, the latter is modifying that structure.